# Unable to get Facebooks "Lookback Video"

Tags: facebook, facebook-lookback

Is this video a one time link? I realize it's still very new and we're all still working out the kinks and such but I was able to view and share it once, then I deleted it. Now when I go back to the link, it just thanks me and the video is no longer there. So is there no chance of viewing this again or what??

Answer (score 0):

> If you delete a post that was featured in the lookback, whether it be
>   a status update or photo you didn't want to see In the video In hopes
>   that maybe it will be replaced for another post you'd like better..
>   then it will no longer work.
>
> My friend has had a Facebook for 7 years, as long as me, yet he wasn't
>   able to view his video because he's literally posted like 3 status
>   updates. So it's my guess that because the video is computer generated
>   to begin with.. it won't work if you tamper with it or don't have
>   enough to go into it. Bummer :/